Pytorch installing
i want to innstall Pytorch 0.4.0 which gives me error so i downgarde my python version to 3.6 but it gives this error.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/torch/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
failed (_ssl.c:749) - skipping
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==0.4.0 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for torch==0.4.0
i downgrade my python version as per requirments but still it gives error

You are trying to install a non-existent version of Pytorch. There's no such thing as Pytorch 0.4.0.
Perhaps you want torch 1.4.0, if so, you can install it by running pip install torch==1.4.0
See the Release history.
